# Get current action in partial view and run jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view with a menu in, depending on the current action i want to show or hide a link, my attempt at this is below

```
@if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "Users")
{
    <script>
        $("#addVS").show();
    </script>
}   
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users", "Users")
        <ul id="addVS" style="display:none;">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "AddEditRecord", "Users",new { mode = "null"}, new { @id = "openDialog" })</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use any javascript but simply conditionally output the anchor on server side:

```
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users", "Users")

    @if (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "Users")
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(
                    "Add New User", 
                    "AddEditRecord", 
                    "Users",
                    new { mode = "null" }, 
                    new { id = "openDialog" }
                )
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're using jQuery, rather than just letting the controller hide or show the `<li></li>`?

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users", "Users")
    @if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "Users")
    {
            <ul id="addVS">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "AddEditRecord", "Users",new { mode = "null"}, new { @id = "openDialog" })</li>
            </ul>
    }   
</li>
```

This way the controller renders the menu when it builds the partial view.

If you *have* to use jQuery to hide or show the link, don't put the script inside the razor conditional statement. Put the script tag in the header or footer of the parent view and use jQuery to check if the condition is true and hide/show accordingly

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(condition is true){
    $("#addVS").show();
}
</script>
```